# Changing the color of a label in a UICollectionViewCell only takes effect in one cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**Introduction** 
I have a collectionView placed in my mainViewController with each DailyCell (custom UICollectionViewCell class) having two labels. I also have a Settings view controller that modifies the color of certain labels of the mainViewController, including those in the collectionViewController via a shared instance (singleton) of the viewController (.Vc). The settings pane changes the colors of all the other labels successfully, except for the ones present in the collectionView of which only two cells change.

**Code** 
Here's the code for the collectionView in my mainViewController.m:

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

// 2
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // 1
    return MIN([[WXManager sharedManager].dailyForecast count], 6) + 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:DayCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //Fetch Data
    WXCondition *weather;
    weather = [WXManager sharedManager].dailyForecast[indexPath.row];
    averageWeather = (weather.tempHigh.floatValue +
                      weather.tempLow.floatValue)/2.0;
    [_cell.labelTemp setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f°",
                              averageWeather]];

    return _cell;
}
```

Here's the custom Daily Cell class code where the two labels are initialized:

```
if (self) {
        s = [Singleton sharedInstance];
        s.Dc = self;
        // Initialize Label Day
        [self.labelDay setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.labelDay];

        // Initialize Label Temp
        [self.labelTemp setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.labelTemp];
return self;
}
```

And here is the part in the settings where I try to change the color of those two labels depending on which static cell in the Settings is picked (i.e. when this cell is tapped in Settings, apply these colors to the labels in the viewController):

```
if ((indexPath.row == 1) && (indexPath.section==0)) {
        //argentum
    s.Dc.labelDay.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    s.Dc.labelTemp.textColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

}
if ((indexPath.row == 0) && (indexPath.section==0)) {
    //album
    s.Dc.labelDay.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    s.Dc.labelTemp.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

**Visual Support** 
[image: Only one changing]
**Question**
Why is only one cell changing and not the rest?

**Update 1** 
Continuously pressing a theme (sometimes) progressively updates the cell labels correctly. Still unsure what is causing this.

Comment: It's hard to grasp all the code you posted and understand it completely, but my intuition points me to that if statement where you have: "if ((indexPath.row == 1) && (indexPath.section==0))". You only allow the code to affect row 1.

Comment: @manecosta if ((indexPath.row == 1) && (indexPath.section==0)) are for the static cells in the settings page; i.e. if this cell is tapped, apply this theme.

Answer (score 1):

if **indexPath.row** is equal to zero means that the first element was selected (WED) if **indexPath.row** is equal to one then you're referring to the second element and so on. There's a method you should try: *didSelectRowAtIndexPath*

```html
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  s.Dc.labelDay.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
  s.Dc.labelTemp.textColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

}
```

I'm not completely sure tho, let me know!

Comment: This acts only when a cell is selected - in my case the cells being 'tapped' act as buttons to change the theme of the app i.e. changing the color of UILabels in another view controller

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you type `s.Dc = self;` in your daily cell, it removes the previous cell that you set at Dc property to replace it with the current one. And so you always have one cell linked to your singleton.

An other way to do it would be to store an enum (let's name it dayCellTheme) in you singleton. That you update when selecting a cell in your SettingsViewController.

Then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource of your collectionViewController, you set the color of your labels accordingly to this property.

Now all you have to do is use a reloadData on your collection view when you leave the settingViewController.

Still i might be wrong about your problem. Let me know !